# Why is PHP not taking over system default locale settings?

Tags: php, locale

```
root@35395c2d434a:/var/www/project# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_GB.utf8
root@35395c2d434a:/var/www/project# echo $LC_MONETARY
en_GB.UTF-8
root@35395c2d434a:/var/www/project#  php -r "echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0).\"\n\";"
C
root@35395c2d434a:/var/www/project#
```

As you can see, I have en_GB.UTF-8 both installed and set in LC_MONETARY environmental variable. But PHP doesn't care and sets it to C anyway. Is there a php configuration so PHP takes this system setting over, so I don't have to set it manually in each PHP script via `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-`8')?

Comment: PHP gets its defaults from its inin file `php.ini`

Comment: That's a cheap answer. I found no configuration which would have any effect on example provided by me.

Comment: Then check the manual, lots of parameters have defaults and some PHP installations dont bother putting those parameters in the `pnp.ini`. You may have to look at the manual and ADD the parameters with the values you want, to override the unwritten defaults

Comment: Maybe this might help http://php.net/manual/en/intl.configuration.php#ini.intl.default-locale

Comment: I did that and found nothing. Please provide concrete answer.  intl.default_locale is something different

Comment: One thing to consider. If you set this from your environment, then the PHP code will only work correctly if its run on your machine. Move the code to some other place that does not have your setup and it will not do the same thing. Maybe you are better setting this in PHP then you know for sure your code will run anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to ensure that PHP uses the locale settings from the OS you have to call `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` at the very beginning of your code.

The manual of `setlocale` under https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php states the following:

```
// If locales is the empty string "", the locale names will be set from 
// the values of environment variables with the same names as the above
// categories, or from "LANG".

// On Windows, setlocale(LC_ALL, '') sets the locale names from the 
// system's regional/language settings (accessible via Control Panel).
```

Your example then looks as follows:

```
abc@ced4c553207d:~/$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_CH.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
abc@ced4c553207d:~/$ locale
LANG=de_CH.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_CH.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_CH.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_CH.UTF-8
abc@ced4c553207d:~/$ php -r "echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0).\"\n\";"
C
abc@ced4c553207d:~/$ php -r " setlocale(LC_ALL, ''); echo setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 0).\"\n\";"
de_CH.UTF-8
abc@ced4c553207d:~/$
```

Comment: This is really strange. On one server "php -r setlocale(LC_ALL, 0)" is returning C as well, on another server the value from system LC_CTYPE is returned. On a third server it is again returning "C", but there it returns the system value with php -a, on the first server php -a returns also "C". Is that due different C versions as explained below?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be limitation of C programs. PHP's setlocale function just returns whatever output returns C's setlocale. From http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php:

> The return value of setlocale() depends on the system that PHP is
>   running. It returns exactly what the system setlocale function
>   returns.

And from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clocale/setlocale/:

> Most running environments have certain locale information set
>   according to the user preferences or localization. But, independently
>   of this system locale, on start, all C programs have the "C" locale
>   set, which is a rather neutral locale with minimal locale information
>   that allows the result of programs to be predictable. In order to use
>   the default locale set in the environment, this function can be called
>   with "" as argument locale.
>
> On program startup, the locale selected is the "C" locale, which is
>   the same as would be set by calling setlocale(LC_ALL,"C").
>
> The locale settings selected in the environment can be selected by
>   calling setlocale(LC_ALL,"").

So as far as I see, there is no way to set this by default for all C programs, nor for PHP.

If someone figures out how to do this for all PHP scripts, I'll accept that answer.

Comment: I have a server with both PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.1 installed. Locale is not set in either configuration or ini files. The return value for setlocale with PHP 7.4 is " en_US.UTF-8" but with PHP 8.1 it's "C". The system locale is "en_US.UTF-8". So I am wondering where PHP is getting this value from.

Comment: From setlocale call in application

Comment: Noticed that as of PHP8, PHP now sets locale to "C" by default no matter what the system setting - including LC_CTYPE - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php